# Unable to print contents of an array

Tags: c

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num[5];
    printf("Enter the numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &num[0] &num[1] &num[2] &num[3] &num[4]);
    printf("Your numbers are : %d %d %d %d %d \n",&num[0]  &num[1]&num[2]&num[3]&num[4]);
}
```

This is the error I get:

> cpractice3.c:7:33: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int
> *' and 'int') scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &num[0] &num[1] &num[2] &num[3] &num[4]);
> ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~ cpractice3.c:8:55: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int') printf("Your
> numbers are : %d %d %d %d %d \n",&num[0] &num[1] &num[2] &num[3]
> &num[4]);

I have googled and figured out how to print the contents of an array using for loop.

I have seen some similar questions here where the answers pointed to int being a pointer and not the actual value.

I am trying to write a simple code which will read the user input of multiple numbers at once and store them at specific index in the array and I don't want to use for loop.

Can anyone tell me what dumb mistake I am making.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need commas.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing commas between parameters.
2. You're passing the addresses of variables to `printf` instead of their values.

Answer (score 0):

pass the variables and add the commas

```
int main(void) {
int num[5];
printf("Enter the numbers: ");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &num[0],&num[1],&num[2],&num[3],&num[4]);
printf("Your numbers are : %d %d %d %d %d \n",num[0] ,num[1],num[2],num[3],num[4]);
return 0;
}
```